# Typescript how to infer type from class constructor arguments

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a class definition that has typed arguments on the constructor. I want to reuse the argument type definition elsewhere without refactoring or extracting the definition from the class. How can I do this. below is an example with a `GetProps<TBase>` type that I was suggested but doesn't actually work. I expect the `const bp` definition to throw an error because it is missing the `derp` field which is defined in the constructor.

```
type GetProps<TBase> = TBase extends new (props: infer P) => any ? P : never

class Bro {
    bro: string = 'cool'
    cool: string = 'lol'
    constructor(props: {bro: string, cool: string, derp: string}){   
        this.bro = props.bro;
        this.cool = props.cool;
    }
}

const bp : GetProps<Bro> = {
    bro: 'lol',
    cool: 'wut'
};
```

Comment: That's because you're passing instance type `Bro` to the utility type `GetProps` instead of constrauctor type. To make this work just `const bp : GetProps<typeof Bro> ...` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwAUBOB7MBnAPAFQEIEN0IA+KAXij0OggA9gIA7AE3SkYgHcoAKMVDAC4oAS0YAzCEigIAlOVL5GIKAH4ZUYRwBuUgFB6AxgBtCbXKigBvPVDtQARqmHpgSMQHNyUAOSGUKMY+tvb+gS5unt4+xoHB9lD+jK5IAK6GwChIfALowlZOKBHujB4ANIkBxsWeFcxSYDWlAL6yVvYhCXbAABYi6AB0hd78aIOFANydXb39A2HGI7nzVVMJzXobRijJwI5gmrDwyGOYoJAo4lAWKKQUNgmFwjFxZdMLz5ypwMHNE0A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript includes a utility type for this: [`ConstructorParameters<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=3#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCBOB7aBvAUNaAjJAuaEALvAJYB2A5tALzQDkwiiIdA3BtI8-kaZTfRDM2aDozK8ArsEKJ4ACgAOSRRHwociHsXIUANJyYhtffdAAmAU3iKTugL4BKFJmgdMhABYkIAOk0Cyoiq-kjsrtBePr5cIIEqfrHh0PZoqWjiRNi20ADCiBLE0rLwAApg8GAAtpaE1hAAPIQAnoqWiABmcEgAfADaAAwAugLoAPQAVBEAetNopSrWLfRWNnTQPtBVPhC6G2SRrZb0Lpp2lKyG3AQ6Fyl0aFiShNDwlgCOkiRv5vuHbSdsHgbqZLrFzhRLqscrxdJd7HRfPIAEwAdgALABGRzQCZjDhnQTCPRiIz4OgAd2eD3srCAA)

```ts
const bp: ConstructorParameters<typeof Bro>[0] = {
/*    ^^
Property 'derp' is missing in type '{ bro: string; cool: string; }'
but required in type '{ bro: string; cool: string; derp: string; }'.(2741) */
  bro: 'lol',
  cool: 'wut'
};
```